# jQuery keyup delaying the result on 'editable' divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a editable 'div' when user edit and insert the letters i am checking the values, in case while the user type on 2 consecutive '//' (forward slashes) i am throwing error..

but on keyup I do this, but i am not getting the error throw, after I type the third letter example ('///') only i am getting the error throw. how to get live output on even 2 time I press the '/' consecutively?

here is my code :

```
<div aria-label="test" contenteditable="true" style="">test</div>

$('div').keyup(function(){
    var value = this.innerText.replace(/\/$/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '').toLowerCase().trim();

    if(value.match('//')){
        alert('this is invalid');
    }
    console.log(value);
})
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Arz69/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the call to `.replace()` in which you remove the last `/` from the string. So basically this is what happens when you type in `/`:

1. The user types `/` and the string `text/` will be converted to `text`
2. The user then types `/` again, and the string is converted to `text/`
3. And finally when the third `/` is typed, the string is converted to `text//` and triggers the `alert()` function.

To fix this, you need to check the string for consecutive slashes before you modify it.

```
$('div').keyup(function(){
    if (this.innerText.match(/\/\/$/)) {
        alert('this is invalid');
    }
    var value = this.innerText.replace(/\/$/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '').toLowerCase().trim();

    console.log(value);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Arz69/2/)

Answer (score 0):

if you replace this line

```
var value = this.innerText.replace(/\/$/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '').toLowerCase().trim();
```

with

```
var value = this.innerText.trim();
```

it will work